# No comprendo sintaxis De angular / Typescript

Tags: typescript, poo

estoy trabajando en una aplicación de angular  la cual tiene una sintaxis que no logro comprender , si bien tengo en claro que es un DTO no comprendo que es lo que se intenta hacer con esta sintaxis:
¿Cual es la función que cumple el DTO en la clase que extiende?
no encontré muchos ejemplos de esta sintaxis en la web, por ende me cuesta comprenderla.

```
export class classejemplo extends classejemplodos<propertysDto> {
    property:string;
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La funcion que tiene `propertysDto` en la clase que se extiende es de darle un tipado a dicha clase, este podria ser una `interface`, `type`, etc.

En los lenguajes de tipado estatico esta funcionalidad es llamado `Generics`, la cual se usa comunmente en clases y funciones donde se les pasa como parametro un tipo de datos para asi tener como resultado componentes genericos, flexibles, reutilizables y tambien ayuda a evitar codigo duplicado.

```js
export interface propertysDto {
  // properties ...
}

export class classejemplodos<T> {
  // code ...
}

export class classejemplo extends classejemplodos<propertysDto> {
  property: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El extends seria así como la herencia en POO, es decir tu clase **classejemplo** hereda todos los atributos y funciones del padre classejemplodos, al hacer esto estas reutilizando las propiedades y métodos, este ultimo puedes sobreescribirlos dependiendo de lo que necesites

Un ejemplo practicó seria figuras geométricas

```
export class FigurasGeometricas<T> {
    lado: number;
    constructor(lado: number) {
        this.lado = lado;
    }
    perimetro() {
        return this.lado * 4;
    }
}
export class FigurasRectangulares {
    ancho: number;
}

class Cuadrado extends FigurasGeometricas<FigurasRectangulares> {
    constructor(lado: number) {
        super(lado);
    }
}

class Rectangulo extends FigurasGeometricas<FigurasRectangulares> {
    ancho: number;
    perimetro() {
        return 2 * (this.lado + this.ancho);
    }
    constructor(largo: number, ancho:number) {
        super(largo);
        this.ancho = ancho;
    }
}


const cuadrado: Cuadrado = new Cuadrado(2);
const rectangulo: Rectangulo = new Rectangulo(3, 2);
console.log('cuadrado: ' + cuadrado.perimetro());
console.log('rectangulo: ' + rectangulo.perimetro());
```